# Python Glob in Classes to access elements from file

Tags: python, glob

Hi there I'm having issues using glob for accessing list of files from multiple subdirectories.

Here is my code:

```
class Folder:
    """Attempt to model typical folder."""

    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path

    def get_folder(self):
        files = glob.glob(os.path.join(self.path, "*"))
        dir_list = []

        for f in files:
            if os.path.isdir(f):
                dir_list = dir_list + [
                    os.path.join(self.path, elt) for elt in os.listdir(f)
                ]
        return dir_list

    def get_file(self):
        dir_list = self.get_folder()
        sf_list = []

        for line in dir_list:
            sep = os.path.sep
            subfiles = glob.glob(sep.join([line, "*"]))
            sf_list.append(subfiles)

        return sf_list
```

Having this as code structure:

```
    datasets 
        Actor1,
            emotion1
                one.wav
                two.wav
            emotion2
                one.wav
                two.wav
        Actor2
            emotion1
                one.wav
                two.wav
            emotion2
                one.wav
                two.wav
```

The output of my `Folder(datasets).get_folder()` is the following.

```
['...\\datasets\\Actor1\\emotion1',
 '...\\datasets\\Actor1\\emotion2',
 '...\\datasets\\Actor2\\emotion2',
 '...\\datasets\\Actor2\\emotion2',]
```

But when I try to access and save into variables the files in the subfolders, calling
`Folder(datasets).get_file()`
Instead of returning all sub-files,

```
['...\\datasets\\Actor1\\emotion1\\one.wav',
 '...\\datasets\\Actor1\\emotion1'\\two.wav',
 '...\\datasets\\Actor2\\emotion2\\one.wav',
 '...\\datasets\\Actor2\\emotion2\\two.wav',]
```

it outputs a list of multiple empty values:
`Out[3]: [ [], [], [], []]`

Could you help?

Comment: You may want to consider using Python's newer `pathlib` builtin library. You might even find that you don't need to create a `Folder` class. https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I need to mantain everything in classes for further development.

Comment: `Path` is a class, and it's a builtin, which means that the Python developers built it and will continue to improve it as Python does. You may want to check out `Path.iterdir()` and `Path.is_file()`. Don't re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I was seeking for wav files, I found the solution to my question hardcoding for specific files I was seeking for.

Not the perfect answer, but a suitable one.

```
def get_file_list(self):
    dir_list = self.get_folder_list()
    for path in sorted(self.path.rglob('*.wav')):
        print(path)
```

thanks to all!

Comment: If you ended up using your own answer, please accept it as the official one.

Comment: I'd like to, but Stack Overflow lets me doing that only tomorrow

Comment: Sure thing, just a friendly reminder :)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this, but this might be a good start for you.

```
import pathlib

class Folder(pathlib.Path):
    def files(self):
        return [f for f in self.iterdir() if f.is_file()]

    def folders(self):
        return [f for f in self.iterdir() if f.is_dir()]
```

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.iterdir.

Comment: Thanks @Bobort ! Although it throws `AttributeError: type object 'Folder' has no attribute '_flavour'`

Comment: Oh, `pathlib.Path` probably requires a `_flavour` attribute. You may want to use `pathlib.PurePath` or `pathlib.WindowsPath`. Check out the documentation for a more appropriate class to inherit from.